# how to know the minimum period of week for two date, increasing by different frequence, to overlap

Tags: php, symfony

to start im sorry for my bad english and i hope that you can understand my problem and finding a solution for it....

my problem is that i have two period

```
the first period:  dateStart1-dateEnd1
the secondperiod:  dateStart2-dateEnd2
```

for the first couple the frequence = 2 :

```
dte=dateStar1;dateEnd1>dte;dte+2week
```

for the second, the frequence = 3 :

```
dte=dateStar2;dateEnd2>dte;dte+3week
```

Exemple:

```
first period  2016-04-04 -> 2016-05-09 
frequence 2 weeks 2016-04-04 , 2016-04-18 , 2016-05-02

the second : 2016-04-11 -> 2016-05-09 
frequence 3 weeks 2016-04-11, 2016-05-02 

the two periods overlaps in 2016-05-02
```

my question in how to know the minimum number of weeks for the two period or dates to overlaps ?
thank you

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the frequence is? I would like to help you but I can't understand that part. :S

Comment: i have two period 
the first : 2016-04-04 ->  2016-05-09
the second : 2016-04-11 -> 2016-05-09
for the first period i have to get the date for every 2 weeks 
2016-04-04 , 2016-04-18 , 2016-05-02
for the second period 
2016-04-11, 2016-05-02
the two periods overlaps in 2016-05-02
in other words, by knowing frequence and the dates how could i know they will overlaps or not ? and thank you very much

Comment: Ok thanks. Is the frequence always an integer number?

Comment: yes it is always an integer number

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better algorithm, but the only thing I can think of is a check on all available weeks for a period.

```
$result = [];
$current = clone $dateStart1;
while ($current < $dateEnd1) {
    // Calculate the difference betweenthe current date and dateStart2
    $diff = $current->diff($dateStart2);

    // Check if the difference is a multiple of the frequency, i.e. if the number of days is congruent to 7 times the frequency
    if ($diff->days % ($frequency2 * 7) == 0) {
        // If the anwser is yes, adds the current date to the list of overlapping dates.
        $result[] = clone $current;
    }

    // Get the next date possible for period 1 by adding $frequency1 weeks to the current date, and then try again till $dateEnd1 is reached.
    $current = $current->add(new \DateInterval('PT'.$frequency1.'W'););
}

return $result;
```

I haven't fully tested it, but this might at least help you to get on the rails.

Comment: first, thank you for your solution it helps me a little bit but i forget to explain somethings <br>
exemple : we have a flight for every 3weeks <br>
and other one for every 2weeks<br>
from 2016-04-05 to 2016-05-09 we have a flight AB6452 every Mon/Thu/Wed<br>
from 2016-04-11 to 2016-05-09 we have a flight AB6452 every Mon,Sat,Sun<br>
the two period overlaps in 2016-04-11 coz the next Mon. is in 2016-04-11<br>
if  the first period start in 2016-04-04 they will overlaps in 2016-05-02<br>
thank you!